# RegExp vs /.../

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to learn regular expressions in Javascript through this brilliant book "Eloquent Javascript" by Marijn Haverbeke. I am unable to figure out why some of these match and why some don't even though they seem fine. I don't know if I have misunderstood something or understood something partially. For example -

```
console.log(/'\d+'/.test("123"));
    // This doesn't match

    console.log(/'\d+'/.test("'123'"));
    // This matches

    let myRegEx = new RegExp("\d+");
    console.log(myRegEx.test("123"));
    //Doesn't match

    console.log(myRegEx.test("'123'"));
    //Doesn't match either
```

Also, why are '' required inside "" for the string to be matched?

Comment: I edited the post to explicitly mention a question that I posed through the examples

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Yes the community wiki answer there covers what is happening to the `\d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

The correct code:

> console.log(/\d+/.test("123"));

or

> let myRegEx = new RegExp("\\d+");
> console.log(myRegEx.test("123"));

You have to add `\` for the `new RegExpr` because `"\\d+"` is a string interpreted as `"\d+"`

> Also, why are '' required inside "" for the string to be matched?

They are not:

`/\d+/` matches "A number, one or more that one time"

`/'\d+'/` matches "A quote, then A number, one or more that one time, then a quote"

So:

> /\d+/.test("123") === true
>
> /'\d+'/.test("123") === false (because `'` are not found)
>
> /\d+/.test("'123'") === true (because numbers are found)
>
> /'\d+'/.test("'123'") === true

Answer (score 1):

`\` is an escape character in string literals as well as regular expressions.

`"\d+"` is the same as `"d+"` so you are testing for 1 or more instances of the character `d`.

Comment: @Adriano — That is documentation for regular expressions. How is that relevant to how string literals are processed (**before** the string is passed to the RegExP constructor function)?